# Can every $n = a^2 + b^2+ c^2$ with $a$, $b$, $c$ imaginary or natural integers

Tags: number-theory

Can any natural number be written as a sum of three squares if we allow imaginary numbers? It is true for every  $n < 100 000$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Suppose that $n$ is odd. Then $n = 2k + 1$ for some $k$, so that $$n = (k+1)^2 - k^2 + 0^2.$$

Suppose that $n$ is even. Then $n = 2k + 2$ for some $k$, so that $$n = (k+1)^2 - k^2 + 1^2.$$

Comment: this is so simple and beautiful. Thank you .

Answer (score 2):

I presume that by "imaginary numbers" you mean Gaussian integers ($r+si$ where $r$ and $s$ are integers). If $a=r+si$ and $b=r-si$ then $a^2+b^2=2(r^2-s^2)=2(r+s)(r-s)$. Clearly one can get all integers congruent to $2$ modulo $4$ in this way. Taking $c=1$ we can get all odd integers as $a^2+b^2+c^2$. In particular this gives all integers congruent to $7$ modulo $8$ which is the sticking point in the classical three-square problem.

Comment: I was not familiar with Gaussian integers. Thank you